# ActiveRecord Where clause using items of array in OR operator

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have an array like this

```
arr = %w[android ios]
```

and I want to use these values in Where clause in a query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM controls
WHERE company_id = '12345' AND (ios > 13 OR android > 14)
```

where the fields inside ( ) are the values of array .. so if i have only one value in array it would be

```
 WHERE company_id = '12345' AND (ios > 13)
```

for example

Is it possible using Ruby on rails ActiveRecord?

Comment: Where do you get this 13 and 14 from?

Comment: this is an arbitrary value .. it could be any number.. it's  just for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need not array but hash like this

```rb
more_than = {
  ios: 13,
  android: 14
}
```

You can build SQL condition string with [sanitize_sql_for_conditions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_conditions) from array with placeholders

```rb
sql_condition_array =
  more_than.each_with_object([]) do |(atr, value), sql_array|
    if sql_array.empty?
      sql_array[0] = "#{atr} > ?"
    else
      sql_array[0] << " OR #{atr} > ?"
    end

    sql_array << value
  end
# => ["ios > ? OR android > ?", 13, 14]

sql_condition = Control.sanitize_sql_for_conditions(sql_condition_array)
# => "ios > 13 OR android > 14"
```

or may be directly

```rb
sql_condition = more_than.map { |atr, value| "#{atr} > #{value}" }.join(" OR ")
# => "ios > 13 OR android > 14"
```

And then

```
Control.where(company_id: 12345).where(sql_condition)
```

The query will be like this:

```
SELECT "controls".* FROM "controls"
WHERE "controls"."company_id" = 12345
AND (ios > 13 OR android > 14);
```

If that hash will consist of just one element, there will be not `OR` used like this:

```
SELECT "controls".* FROM "controls"
WHERE "controls"."company_id" = 12345
AND (ios > 13);
```

Answer (score 0):

define a hash instead of an array,  `hash = { 'android' => 14, 'ios' => 13}`

and then form a string that can be passed to `where`

Complete code looks like this

```
hash = { 'android' => 14, 'ios' => 13}
str = ''
hash.each do |k, v|
    str += k + ' > ' + v.to_s + ' OR '
end
Control.where(company_id: '12345').where(str[0..-5])
```

Comment: How will this work with one element? What is magic `-5`?

Comment: It will work with any no. Of elements present in the hash.  `-5` is for ignoring last four characters from str which will be `' OR '`

Comment: Looks tricky :) There is `Array#join` method for this

Answer (score 0):

A more ActiveRecord approach:

```rb
Control.where(company_id: 12345).where("ios > ?", 13).or(Control.where(company_id: 12345).where("android > ?", 14))
```

Better way:

```rb
controls = Control.where(company_id: 12345)
controls = controls.where("ios > ?", 13).or(controls.where("android > ?", 14))
```

This generates the next SQL query:

```
SELECT "controls".* FROM "controls" WHERE "controls"."company_id" = 12345 AND (ios > 13 OR android > 14)
```

Comment: How about hash / array as OP wanted?